# Loading compile time constants from properties file

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I am working on a java application, where in we receive xml, the xml contains some data from a lot of regions across the globe. So xml looks something like this

```
<Shipment>
         <Region>
                <name>China</name>
                <calculatedValue>0.001</calculatedValue>
                <deviation>-1<deviation>  
         </Region>
         <Region>
                <name>Russia</name>
                <calculatedValue>0.091</calculatedValue>
                <deviation>-1<deviation>  
         </Region>
         <Region>
                <name>UK</name>
                <calculatedValue>2.001</calculatedValue>
                <deviation>-12<deviation>  
         </Region>
         // lots of other regions //
</Shipment>
```

We have one pojo called Dock.

```
public class Dock {

  private Map<SupportedRegion, Region> regionalShipmentDetails = //
  //some field and getter setter.
  getChinaShipmentDetails () { this.regionalShipmentDetails.get(SupportedRegions.CHINA)}
  setChinaShipmentDetails (Region china) {
      this.regionalShipmentDetails.get(SupportedRegions.CHINA).add(china)
  }

  getRussiaShipmentDetails () {//same for russia}
  setRussiaShipmentDetails (Region russia) {same for russia}
}
```

We extract the region out of this xml create a region object and add to Dock object. 
Now we also maintain a enum, which defines all the supported by our application.

```
enum SupportedRegions{
     CHINA (201, "APAC"),
     RUSSIA (202, "EUR")  
}
```

Now we are getting requirement to support other regions as well. Now we want to refactor our code so that it becomes easy and configurable to support regions by support team.

We want to move it out of code and maintain in a property file with minimal changes. 
We have some calling code like.

```
dock.getChinaShipmentDetails()
dock.getRussiaShipmentDetails ().
```

Now if i remove the enum and move all the regions in properties. I will have to modify my Dock class to something like this

```
private Map<String, Region> regionalShipmentDetails = //
  //some field and getter setter.
  getShipmentDetailsForRegion (String region) { this.regionalShipmentDetails.get(region)
  }
}
```

Now my caller will becomes

```
 Region china = dock.getShipmentDetailsForRegion ("region")
```

Now i dont want to introduce the hardcoded string values in code,because this change affects my caller class and now its become the responsibility of caller class to pass the correct reion, previously Dock was exposing method fore regions supported only.

Is there any way at compile time i dont have to use hardcoded string.

Comment: You can only load constants from properties files at runtime, No compile time loading allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that generates code with enums or static final variables from an XML file or some other format. Then you run this script automatically during the build process. As far as I remember, build tools like Ant can do this.

Comment: there is a slight wrinkle with that approach, we keep configurations as a separate project and binaries as a separate project. Reason being if there is a config change, we change the config and release the changes which takes hardly 45 mins, but releasing binaries is a length process we do not want that every time we want to add a region, we should not be releasing a new code version in production

Comment: You do not need to rebuild the complete project, just generate the classes which contain the config information and replace them.